Donde esta el error que no se manda el formulario javascript
Hola copie este codigo de internet y no se porque no me envia el formulario.. el HTML
<form action="mailEnvio.php" method="POST" id="form">
....
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="margin-top: 5px;text-align: center;width: 100%;color: #000000;background: #f4f4f4;" id="submit">Enviar</button>

y javascript así:
    const nombre = document.getElementById("name");
    const email = document.getElementById("email");
    const mensaje = document.getElementById("mensaje");
    const form = document.getElementById("form");
    const suma = document.getElementById("sumas");
    const parrafo = document.getElementById("warnings");
    form.addEventListener("submit", e=>{
      e.preventDefault()
      let warnings =""
      let entrar=false
      let regexEmail = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/
      parrafo.innerHTML=""
      if(nombre.value.length <4){
        warnings +=`El nombre no es valido <br>`
        entrar = true
      }
      if(!regexEmail.test(email.value)){
        warnings +=`El Email no es valido <br>`
        entrar = true
    
      }
      if(mensaje.value.length<20){
        warnings +=`El Mensaje es muy corto <br>`
        entrar = true
    
      }
      if(suma.value.length<1){
        warnings +=`Ingrese la repuesta <br>`
        entrar = true
      }
     if(entrar){
      parrafo.innerHTML=warnings
    
     }
     
    })

¿Porque no envia mi formulario? Lo copié exactamente y lo tengo en archivos separados. El de javascript lo pegue antes de cerrar en body, casi al final.

El problema principal es que el JavaScript está previniendo el envío del formulario con e.preventDefault() y solo lo permite si no hay advertencias (warnings). Pero, aún si no hubiera advertencias, no estás dejando que se envíe el envío del formulario.
Acá te dejo los códigos modificados...
(HTML) fijate de que el formulario tiene todos los elementos necesarios y que los IDs coinciden con los usados en el JavaScript:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Formulario de Contacto</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="mailEnvio.php" method="POST" id="form">
        <label for="name">Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>
        
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br>
        
        <label for="mensaje">Mensaje:</label>
        <textarea id="mensaje" name="mensaje"></textarea><br>
        
        <label for="sumas">Suma 2 + 2:</label>
        <input type="text" id="sumas" name="sumas"><br>
        
        <p id="warnings"></p>
        <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </form>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Y acá te dejo el JavaScript. Solo fijate de que está en un archivo llamado script.js o el nombre que te salga de las arterias noc, y que esté bien referenciado con el HTML. Saludaso crack cualquier cosa volveme a preguntar, queres.
const nombre = document.getElementById("name");
const email = document.getElementById("email");
const mensaje = document.getElementById("mensaje");
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const suma = document.getElementById("sumas");
const parrafo = document.getElementById("warnings");

form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    let warnings = "";
    let entrar = false;
    let regexEmail = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/;
    parrafo.innerHTML = "";

    if (nombre.value.length < 4) {
        warnings += `El nombre no es válido <br>`;
        entrar = true;
    }

    if (!regexEmail.test(email.value)) {
        warnings += `El Email no es válido <br>`;
        entrar = true;
    }

    if (mensaje.value.length < 20) {
        warnings += `El Mensaje es muy corto <br>`;
        entrar = true;
    }

    if (suma.value.length < 1) {
        warnings += `Ingrese la respuesta <br>`;
        entrar = true;
    }

    if (entrar) {
        parrafo.innerHTML = warnings;
    } else {
        // Si no hay advertencias, permite que el formulario se envíe
        form.submit();
    }
});


Hola Muchas gracias, el dilema son dos, al no tener preventdefaul... se recarga el formulario y borra toda la info de los input , teniéndola que poner de nuevo.. y no se ven los mensaje donde el usuario se ha equivocado. Se agradece mucho ya que estoy aprendiendo este codigo ,, intente con settimea setTimeout().. pero no funciona.

En general, no recomiendo copiar y pegar código del Internet sin estudiarlo y comprender primero su funcionamiento.
Por un lado, es común encontrar código que tiene errores básicos, como también es frecuente que el código no se adapte al 100% y, al no entenderlo, lo rompamos al intentar adaptarlo.
Esto, por no hablar de la pérdida de oportunidad para el aprendizaje.
Leyendo el código que publicas en la pregunta, entiendo la intención del programador original y puedo ver varios fallos.
Explicando su intención, y esto en función de ayudarte a tí a entenderlo (esfuerzo que debieras hacer por tí mismo), lo que yo veo es:

La intención de realizar validaciones, y si estas validaciones pasan, dejar que se envíe el formulario.
Si las validaciones no pasan, entonces, mostrar una serie de mensajes al usuario haciéndole ver los problemas y entonces el formulario no será enviado, para darle chance de corregir los problemas.
A medida que se van realizando las validaciones, de manera secuencial, se va dejando los mensajes con los problemas en la variable warnings.

En la implementación en código, veo varios problemas:

Se llama al método preventDefault() del evento muy temprano, apenas antes de realizar ninguna validación. Esto, si bien habría forma de hacerlo funcionar, es incorrecto.
Lo recomendable es llamar a este método solo si las validaciones fallan. Si piensas en el nombre del método, tiene sentido prevenir el envío del formulario solo si las validaciones han fallado.

Se declara y se utiliza una variable entrar que, por ser información redundante, está de más. Estas variables con información redundante suelen ser fuente de muchos errores. Acá, si la variable warnings es distinto de la cadena vacía, es que hubo algún error, ya que se inicializa con "" y se le agregan mensajes a medida que se van realizando las validaciones.


Con esta comprensión, diría que resulta fácil, no solo adaptar, sino escribir el código desde 0 para cualquier formulario, hagamos un par de experimentos, que puedes probar aquí mismo en el navegador:


const inum1 = document.getElementById("num1");
const inum2 = document.getElementById("num2");
const isuma = document.getElementById("suma");
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const parrafo = document.getElementById("warnings");

form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
    let warnings = "";
    parrafo.innerHTML = "";
    let num1 = parseFloat(inum1.value);
    let num2 = parseFloat(inum2.value);
    let sum = parseFloat(isuma.value);
    if (inum1.value == "") warnings += "Debe ingresar el número 1<br>";
    if (inum2.value == "") warnings += "Debe ingresar el número 2<br>";
    if (isuma.value == "") warnings += "Debe ingresar la suma de ambos<br>";
    if (!isNaN(num1) & !isNaN(num2) & !isNaN(sum) & sum != num1 + num2) warnings += "La suma es incorrecta";
    if (warnings !== "") {
        parrafo.innerHTML = warnings;
        e.preventDefault();
    } 
});
label {
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
}
input {
  width: 225px;
}
textarea {
  width: 225px;
}
.warnings {
  color: red;
}
<form action="mailEnvio.php" method="POST" id="form">
    <label for="num2">Número 1:</label>
    <input type="number" id="num1" name="num1"><br>

    <label for="num2">Número 2:</label>
    <input type="number" id="num2" name="num2"><br>

    <label for="suma">Suma:</label>
    <input type="number" id="suma" name="suma"><br>

    <p id="warnings"></p>
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>





const nombre = document.getElementById("name");
const email = document.getElementById("email");
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const parrafo = document.getElementById("warnings");

form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    let warnings = "";
    let regexEmail = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/;
    parrafo.innerHTML = "";
    if (nombre.value.length < 4) warnings += `El nombre no es válido <br>`;
    if (!regexEmail.test(email.value)) warnings += `El Email no es válido <br>`;
    if (warnings !== "") {
        parrafo.innerHTML = warnings;
        e.preventDefault();
    } 
});
label {
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
}
input {
  width: 225px;
}
textarea {
  width: 225px;
}
.warnings {
  color: red;
}
<form action="mailEnvio.php" method="POST" id="form">
    <label for="name">Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br>

    <p id="warnings"></p>
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>



Creo que con esto, tienes lo necesario para realizar tu propia adaptación del código, eres libre de copiar y pegar, hace básicamente lo que el código de tu pregunta debiera hacer y ya te he explicado con detalle su funcionamiento como para que continúes tú a partir de este punto.

Hola Gracias por responder, estoy tratando de aprender y el tiempo es tirano, lo vi en YouTube, un señor conocido, pero no anduvo. lo hice tal cual. Al agregar “preventdefaul”, ocurren dos cosas buenas, 1° al no recargar la página no me borra los datos del formulario, que envía el mensaje, 2° los mensajes de error se mantienen.
Sin saber mucho eso es muy bueno para el usuario. No tener que cargar los datos nuevamente y saber dónde se equivocó.
El código que me han pasado si sirven, pero es tan rápido que no puedo ver donde me equivoque
Saludos y se agradece.!!

¿cómo te ha funcionado esta explicación?

En la validacion donde quiera que se envie el formulario debes colocar lo siguiente form.submit(); Por lo que veo del codigo en caso de que no se active ningun validacion quiere decir que el formulario se puede enviar, por lo que la linea de codigo de envio quedaria de esta forma.
Sin eso el formulario no se envia.
if(entrar)
{      
  parrafo.innerHTML=warnings
}
form.submit(); //esto envia el formulario
})


Hola Muchas gracias por tu repuesta, cualquier duda estaré preguntando de nuevo, estoy aprendiendo....
